# How to make a dynamic tableau x-axis that gets changed when a different dimension is selected as a filter?

Tags: data-visualization, tableau-api, visualization

I am trying to create a report for my stakeholders where we want to check the distribution by values of column1, column2 and likewise. While I could make different tabs for each column, I apparently have 55 columns (*all numeric and I will be making bins for them*) that the user want to toggle between for comparison on distributions - and coming up with an insight like column 43 is more skewed than column19.

Pet example:

**1.** Suppose I have data in below format:

[image]

**2.** And I want to create a tableau filter enabling the user to toggle between continents and countries, and get their individual distributions in the same view. I want to keep the measure consistent (population in this example). Something like below:

[image]

**3.** and generating distribution by continent when continent is selected and by country when country is selected

[image]

I know if I had wanted to toggle between different measures for the same dimension, then I needed to create parameters, but this is opposite to it (same measure but different dimensions) and I am not able to figure out.

Any comment/help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid you'd still need to use parameters. There is no equivalent of `Measure Names` for dimensions so you'll have to create a parameter (I called it `Dimension Switch`) with Continent, Country, etc. as options and a calculated field that will look something like this:

```
CASE Dimension Switch
  WHEN "Continent" THEN [Continent]
  WHEN "Country" THEN [Country]
END
```

This calculated field will take on the values of whichever column you have selected in the `Dimension Switch` parameter.